# Magento Links Add Unnecessary :void() Call

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a Magento store where product page links work properly but add an unnecessary :void() call at the end. For example:

```
https://beautygables.com/bath-body/deodorants.html :void();
```

These links are reported by SEMrush as "Malformed URL Discovered" even though the pages load correctly when clicked.

The extra :void() call seems to be causing issues with the Google crawler and SEO tools. I've tried fixing it manually but :void() keeps getting appended to many links.

What could be causing Magento/PHP to add this pointless :void() to links?

How can I debug and solve this to generate clean links without the extra function call?

Any help is appreciated!
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dBWu.png)

my website is [www.beautygables.com](http://www.beautygables.com)